# how to check array in where condition in codeigniter?

Tags: sql, arrays, codeigniter

in code igniter a group of student details check in fore-each loop ,the student get by the bases of student admission number

my admission numbers are in **$ad_no=$this->input->post('adn_no');** :-

> array(5) { [0]=> string(5) "11784" [1]=> string(5) "11837" [2]=>
>   string(5) "11775" [3]=> string(5) "11937" [4]=> string(5) "12061" }

i try to select these admission numbers student, but the result show only first student result
.

my code:

```
foreach($ad_no as $key => $id) {
        $this - > db - > where_in('ad_no', $id);
        $query = $this - > db - > get('duration');
        $r = $query - > result_array();
        $dur = $r[0]['tot_hr'];
        $start = explode(':', $dur);
        $end = explode(':', $tm);
        $total_hours = $start[0] - $end[0];
        $total_hours1 = $start[1] - $end[1];
        $mins = abs($total_hours1);
        $dur = $total_hours.":".$mins;
        $durs[$key] =
            array(
                'ad_no' => $ad_no[$key],
                'tot_hr' => $dur
            );
    }
    $reslt = $this - > Daily_temp_model - > duration($durs);
```

Comment: 'duration' is the name of a table?

Comment: When/where does the value of `$tm` get set?

Comment: Please provide an example value for `$dur` from this call `$dur = $r[0]['tot_hr'];`

Comment: @DFriend duration is table name and $tm is settwd ,$dur=61:60

Comment: i am var_dump the $r in out side of the loop show only one result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using array push in foreach loop

```
$result=[];
foreach($ad_no as $key => $id) {
    $this->db->where_in('ad_no', $id);
    $query = $this-> db-> get('duration');
    $r = $query-> result_array();
    array_push($result, $r);
    $dur = $r[0]['tot_hr'];
    $start = explode(':', $dur);
    $end = explode(':', $tm);
    $total_hours = $start[0] - $end[0];
    $total_hours1 = $start[1] - $end[1];
    $mins = abs($total_hours1);
    $dur = $total_hours.":".$mins;
    $durs[$key] =
        array(
            'ad_no' => $ad_no[$key],
            'tot_hr' => $dur
        );
}
$reslt = $this->Daily_temp_model->duration($durs);
```

Comment: Why is there gaps between arrows `- >`

Comment: @wolfgang1983 it just ignored by php intrepreter, it's just his style to type.

Answer (score 1):

using in_array

```
<?php
$a = array('1.10', 12.4, 1.13);

if (in_array('12.4', $a, true)) {
    echo "'12.4' found with strict check\n";
}

if (in_array(1.13, $a, true)) {
    echo "1.13 found with strict check\n";
}
?>
```